# Find specific cell Excel VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to define a variable in a for loop as a specific cell that will change as the for loop iterates through.  I am just unsure of the syntax to do so. This is what I have so far.  How could I make this do what I just explained? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Key = Sheet1.Columns("A:A").Rows("i")
```

Comment: can you post your loop code?  You should be able to do something like Key = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value    This assumes that i is your loop iterator.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to refer to the cell *as a Range object*, then:

```
Dim Key as Range
Set Key = Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
```

You must use the `Set` keyword when assigning to an object variable. A `Range` is an object.

If you need to refer only to the cell's *value*, then:

```
Dim Key as Variant
Key = Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
```

I declare `Key` as type `Variant` because cells may contain error values/etc. which will cause an error if you strictly define the variable as type like `String` or `Long`, etc.